# Can i test applepay in localhost react?

Tags: reactjs, applepayjs

Hi I'm trying to test applepay on localhost but get the following error
`InvalidAccessError: Trying to start an Apple Pay session from an insecure document`
How should I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't appear that Apple Pay can be tested from localhost because the domain name needs to be registered and Apple servers need to be able to communicate to it.

Answer (score 0):

The domain (web site) must be registered with Apple, but once this is done you can run the application locally exposing an HTTPS URL, for example using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

```
$ ngrok HTTP 8080

Forwarding                    https://43e9-24-132-87-22.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8080
```

Use `https://43e9-24-132-87-22.ngrok.io` to access the local application and initiate the ApplePay session.